# src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, github

I created a repository in my git account which is named "recommender" and then I opened git bash in my local project which I want to put in git and executed these commands:

```
$ git checkout -b recommender
$ git commit -m "My first commit"
$ git push -u origin master
$ error: src refspec master does not match any.
```

And when I execute:

```
$ git branch
* recommender
```

I get a list containing just one name: "recommender"

I need to put my already existing project in recommender branch. How to do so? and what does the error mean?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are mixing a lot of stuff here. You created a branch names recommender not a project. Obviously the error message says you don't have master branch. Maybe you read a tutorial about the git basics because here I see a huge lack of understanding.

Comment: I know it's not a project. can you suggest to me a tutorial about how to use git? I didn't like the one provided by git. I prefer it with an example of project.

Comment: No, the git tutorial is perfect. Otherwise you can use your fingers and go to www.google.com and look for tutorial that fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> error: src refspec master does not match any.

Means you have no `master` branch. No branch exists with empty commit. When you create a repo `master` is Default branch but you didn't do any commit in `master`. You just checked out `recommender` branch and did the commit so master doesn't exist in `git branch` command.

> I need to put my already existing project in recommender branch

Push your commits to remote `recommender` branch instead of `master`.

```
$ git push -u origin recommender  # push to origin/recommender

$ git fetch                       # sync all update
$ git branch -a                   # see all local & remote branches
```

Comment: Try this `git push -u origin recommender`